# Question about the PLONK permutation check

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

From the [PLONK paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf).

On pages 19 & 20, the paper describes the prescribed permutation check in PLONK.

[image]

In the last step of the proof, these are the checks

a) $L_1(a)(Z(a) - 1) = 0$
b) $Z(a)f'(a) = g'(a)Z(a \cdot g)$

In (a), I think checking $Z(a) - 1 = 0$ & doing the (b) check as written is enough. What purpose does multiplying this by the first Lagrange Polynomial ($L_1(a)$) serve?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checks a) and b) are done over every element $a\in H$ (Notice the statement "for all $a\in H$"). The product check requires that the verifier check that $Z(g)=1$ (the inductive base case). Since $L_1$ only evaluates to $1$ (otherwise $0$) at $g$, checking $L_1(a)(Z(a)-1)=0$ over all $a\in H$ is exactly the same as checking $Z(g)-1=0\implies Z(g)=1$. If we were to check $Z(a)-1=0$ for all $a\in H$ instead, that check would translate to "does Z(X) evaluate to only 1 over every element of $H$."

Comment: There are 2 sets here. First is $[n]$ which is $[1,2,...,n]$ & the 2nd is $H = \{g, g^2, g^3, ..., 1\}$ - last element is $1$ because $g^n = 1$ because order of $g$ is $1$. I think the subscript of $L_1$ is the $1$ taken from $[n]$. However since the first element of $H$ is $g$ wouldn't $Z(a)$ be $Z(g)$ rather than $Z(1)$? it's $Z(last element of H)$ which will be $Z(1)$ - i.e we have to prove $Z(g) = 1$ & not $Z(1) = 1$, right? Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Ah, yes, it depends on how you do indexing. I was originally referring to the multiplicative identity $1$ of the group $H$. Normally, people use $0$ indexing, which is what led to me using $g^0=1$. I'll edit the answer to match the plonk indexing.